# Can i crack usb security dongle?

Tags: reverse-engineering, usbserial, cracking, dongle

I have to develop a plugin for a program that uses dongle to activate.Just wondering can i crack the key of the usb or something else?

Comment: Have you considered a legitimate approach, such as contacting the manufacturer of the program and explaining that you are a plugin developer and finding out what kind of terms they might provide you a license?

Comment: the creator of the plugin that uses dongle is dead... so there is no update no contact nothing...

Comment: Ah. Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure you *can*, but you might be running afoul of the various legislation regarding the act of reverse engineering content protection systems. I am, of course, referring to the American DCMA statues.

In any event, as pure thought experiment, I might try the following:

- Clone the USB firmware image, and load it into a virtual USB port
- As you say, crack the key and the USB interface, and short-circuit the check in a virtual USB device.
- Locate the part of the code in the program that is doing the security check, and edit the bytecode / machine code to return successful without actually looking for the device.

**NOTE**: Do not contact me for services related to defeating security systems.  I won't do it, and I'll probably lecture you.

Comment: ok thank you hope to do that :)...why the users are voting down i dont understand?

Comment: Down votes are because the act of circumventing the copy protection is illegal.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Only if it says as much in the TOS.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy what would be the point of a security dongle if you would allow people to crack it?  Anyway, better check your references. I'm not much of a lawyer, but [17 U.S. Code § 1201(a)(1)(A)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/1201) states: No person shall circumvent a technological measure that effectively controls access to a work protected under this title.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer No, you're certainly not a lawyer: In a nutshell, the DMCA makes it illegal to produce/share copyrighted works. It also makes it illegal to offer services/products designed to circumvent copyright protection. Which has nothing to do with the topic at hand. (We're specifically discussing TOS here.) If you're curious as to why a company would challenge people to break their security, refer yourself to [one of the many examples](https://tresorit.com/contest/hacking-challenge) which you can find online.