# Senselock EliteIV v2.x usb dongle dump or emulate?

Tags: usb, reverse-engineering, dump, cracking, dongle

OK, I got a Senselock EliteIV v.2.x USB Dongle and I want to emulate the hardware so I can still run the LaserCut 5.3 Software without it ?

Here is the link from others which similar with mine : 
   http://binarydb.com/driver/Senselock-EliteIV-v2.x-24981.html

```
  Senselock Elite IV v2.x.
  Beijing Senselock Corp.
    VID - 0471 
    REV - 0303 
    PID - 485d
```

How to dump its firmware image and make the virtual USB Port as Smart Card reader ?


PS :
2 years ago, another guy also asking the same question as me at :
        http://www.reteam.org/board/showthread.php?t=4360

I already read the following post at : 
  [Can i crack usb security dongle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435089/can-i-crack-usb-security-dongle)
  [Programmable USB dongles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377240/programmable-usb-dongles?rq=1)

And I'm running my USB Dongle at Windows XP and Windows 7 64bit.